# Cannot replicate odds ratio

Tags: odds-ratio

I am trying to replicate some odds ratio calculations which are reported in this [paper](http://www.drchrishobbs.com/uploads/8/2/1/2/8212308/hpv__hnscc.pdf).
For example in the paper on page 3 in the Strome et al. data for tonsil:
it states there are 52 cases and 48 controls. HPV % cases = 40% and controls = 6%.

Converting the percentages to raw figures, I get the following 2×2 table:

```
               Case  Control
HPV positive     21        3   
HPV negative     31       45
```

Therefore the odds ratio should $=\frac{21\cdot45}{31\cdot3} = 10.16$.

However the paper reports this particular odds ratio as 18.2 on the following page. 
Does anyone know why this is? Are they using a different formula?

Comment: Actually if you look at figure 1, the Strome 2002 data shows odds ratio of: 10.2 (2.8, 37.0), so that 18.2 looks like a typo to me. Also in figure 2 they report the OR as 10.2 from Strome data.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments:
Actually if you look at figure 1, the Strome 2002 data shows odds ratio of: 10.2 (2.8, 37.0), so that 18.2 looks like a typo to me. Also in figure 2 they report the OR as 10.2 from Strome data. – bdeonovic